# XML serialization with XML web service

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I have a web-service that returns a XML in one of the object parameters.

When I query my service, I get the following error:

```
An exception ocurred while executing the query [Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.]
```

This happens because the web-service encodes the result.

If I run using Visual Studio WCF Test Client, I can get a result like this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header />
  <s:Body>
  <QueryResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <QueryResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/UpgradeMeWS" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <a:ErrorMessage />
    <a:ExecutionError>false</a:ExecutionError>
    <a:OperationResult>&lt;![CDATA[&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?&gt;&lt;       ...
```

Note that OperationResult is encoded, and the query was right, but why this error always happens when I use some other application?

How do I decode this message to avoid this kind of error? This XML is just a string inside the object, but I don't know how to manage this.

My result class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Result
{
    string errorMessage    = "";
    string operationResult = "";

    [DataMember]
    public string ErrorMessage
    {
        get { return errorMessage; }
        set { errorMessage = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    // This is my XML
    public string OperationResult
    {
        get { return operationResult;  }
        set { operationResult = value; }
    }
}
```

My ServiceContract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IUpgradeMe
{
    [OperationContract]
    Result Query(string userName, string password);
}
```

Comment: Show the stack trace, please.

Comment: it probably doesnt help - anyway, can you try with datacontract(namespace=""), and see if the error repros.

Comment: I guess I didn't understand your questions =x ...you mean my web-service result data contract? It's the Result class =) .."OperationResult" is filled out with a XML string but I can't decode.. i just get this error

Comment: I included my ServiceContract too =)

Comment: Check your data to see if you have any HTML tags in it. Or greater than and less than symbols.